# Size of my Like Box changed on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-likebox

The IFRAME code on my page www.iluminet.com.mx is the following:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Filuminet&amp;width=250&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;stream=true&amp;header=false&amp;height=400" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:400px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When checking this on mobile devices like iPad and iPhone the box modifies its set size.